# SSRS- SUM in IIF not working

Tags: reporting-services

I am new into SSRS and trying to retrieve the sum of the column when the column `CODATE = 0`.

The expression I am using is as follows:

```
=SUM(IIF(Fields!CODATE.Value=0,Fields!CURBAL.Value,00.00))
```

The rendering is not happening at all. However, when  I am just trying the IIF, it works fine. What could be wrong?

The data types of the variables are as follows:

```
CODATE: int

CURBAL: float(null allowed).
```

I basically want to sum all the values when the codate column is 0,  but it isnt working. I get a warning for telling `rsAggregateofNonNumericData`.

Comment: Did you try this?: `=IIF(Fields!CODATE.Value=0,SUM(Fields!CURBAL.Value),00.00)`

Comment: Yes but no luck. I tried to create a calculated field and then to sum that field as well but it gives #Error. Can someone please help

Comment: what if you do this? - convert it to a decimal and then sum it? =IIF(Fields!CODATE.Value=0,SUM(cdec(Fields!CURBAL.Value)),00.00)

Comment: You can modify your query that you return 0 for CURBAL when CODATE is 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may be treating 0 as null. Try converting with cint/cdec:

`=SUM(IIF(Fields!CODATE.Value=cint(0),Fields!CURBAL.Value,cdec(00.00)))`